# Google Play Music - Error while retrieving information from server

Tags: google-play-store, google, google-play-music

**Google Play Music** - Error while retrieving information from server. When tapping **Get Started**. Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clear data and cache of the app and then try.If it doesn't work then you can wipe dalvik cache in recovery and reboot.

Comment: I already did that and it didn't work.